# Highlight multiple keywords advanced

Tags: php, html, arrays, highlight, keyword

I tried most of solution answered here but all of them have same problem which is my question here.

I use this function for highligh search results:

```
function highlightWords($searchtext, $searchstrings){   
        $searchstrings = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($searchstrings));
        $words = explode(' ', $searchstrings);

        $highlighted = array();
        foreach ( $words as $word ){
            $highlighted[] = "<font color='#00f'><b>".$word."</b></font>";
        }

        return str_replace($words, $highlighted, $searchtext);
    }
```

Problem occurs when i search text with 2 or more strings separated with spaces and any of them have any of HTML code from my highlighted array.

For example, searchtext="I have max system performance" AND searchstrings="max f"

In first iteration foreach will replace every **max** with `<font color='#00f'><b>max</b></font>`

In second iteration it will replace every **f** with `<font color='#00f'><b>f</b></font>`

Second iteration will also replace html tags inserted in first replacement!
So it will replace **f** in string `<font color='#00f'>` also?

Any suggestion?
Thanks
Miodrag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $searchtext = "I have max system performance";
    $searchstrings = "max f";
    $searchstrings = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($searchstrings));
    $words = explode(' ', $searchstrings);
    $highlighted = array();
    foreach ( $words as $word ){
        $highlighted[] = "<font color='#00f'><b>".$word."</b></font>";
    }
    echo strtr($searchtext, array_combine($words, $highlighted));
?>
```

Comment: This is same situation. Foreach loop for second string will also replace html code inserted in first loop!

Comment: This looks very clever but nothing is highlighted... still debugging

Comment: Not 1 char, if second string (which is found by the search) have anything which is inserted as a highlight code, it will be replaced as well (just tried search "max nt", "nt" is replaced inside <font>. In your updated code str_replace doesn't do anything :-(

Comment: Hm, I can't get it work. I got error: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric. I'm not so familiar with reg exp :-(

Comment: I have edited the code above. its working. you just have to add your function and instead of echoing return it and it will work for you

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. I just realise it is case sensitive. Do you have idea how to highlight insensitive? One more time, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
foreach ( $words as $word ){
   if(strlen ($word)>2)
   {
      $highlighted[] = "<font color='#00f'><b>".$word."</b></font>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is good Solution for you?

```
 function highlightWords($searchtext, $searchstrings){   
        $searchstrings = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($searchstrings));
        $words = explode(' ', $searchstrings);

        $highlighted = array();
        foreach ( $words as $word ){
            $highlighted[] = '<span class="highlighted-word">'.$word.'</span>';
        }

        return str_replace($words, $highlighted, $searchtext);
    }

echo highlightWords('I have max system performance', 'max f');


?>
```

You need to add a little bit CSS on your Page:

```
<style>
.highlighted-word {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Outputs: 
I have **max** system per**f**ormance

### ---

**UPDATE:**
If you like to hightlight the complete word, look at this:

```
function highlightCompleteWords($searchtext, $searchstrings){   
        $searchstrings = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($searchstrings));
        $words = explode(' ', $searchstrings);


        $highlighted = array();
        foreach ( $words as $word ){
            $searchtext = preg_replace("/\w*?".preg_quote($word)."\w*/i", "<span class='highlighted-word'>$0</span>", $searchtext);
        }

        return $searchtext;
    }


echo highlightCompleteWords('I have max system performance', 'max f');
```

Outputs: I have **max** system **performance**

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if I search for example "some las", in a first loop it will change 'some' with '<span class=......', in second loop it will find 'las' in '<span class=' :-(  Hope you understand...

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand your question, but I guess you want to highlight every matched word in the search string.

You could probably just do something like:

```
 $returnString = $searchtext;
    foreach ( $words as $word ){
       $returnString = preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/i', "<font color='#00f'><b>$0</b></font>", $returnString);
    }
 return $returnString;
```

This would output: *"I have **max** system performance"*

Since the *"f"* wouldn't get matched

**EDIT** - This is if you wanna match part of a word as well.

Kind of ugly but I believe this will fork for you

```
$returnString = $searchtext;
    foreach ( $words as $word ){
       if(strlen($word)>2){
          $returnString = preg_replace('/'.$word.'/i', "§§§$0###", $returnString);
       }
    }
$returnString = preg_replace("/\§§§/","<font color='#00f'><b>", $returnString);
$returnString = preg_replace("/\###/","</b></font>", $returnString);

return $returnString;
```

Comment: Why 'f' wouldn't matched? There is 'f' in 'performance' AND also in '<font color...' replaced in first foreach loop. Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to get matched? thought you only wanted to highlight matched words, not characters?

Comment: Yes, I want any of searched strings to be found (except one string smaller than 3 char)

Comment: @MiTja was this a solution?